# Remove items from a list of objects which key value doesn't exist in another one

Tags: java, list

I have two following classes.

```java
    public class RetailerExcelConversionDto {
        private String retailerCode;
        private Integer isActive;
    }
    
        public class RetailerDto {
            private String code;
            private Integer age;
            private String name;
        
        }
```

And I have these following list

```java
    List<RetailerExcelConversionDto> retailerConversionDtoList = getAllRetailerConversionDtoList();
    List<RetailerDto> retailerDtoList = getAllRetailer();
```

What I want to achieve is remove item from retailerConversionDtoList which key value (retailerCode) doesn't exist in retailerDtoList key value (code); In short I want to remove items from retailerConversionDtoList which doesn't exist in retailerDtoList how can I do that in optimized way?

Comment: OK ... And what is your actual question/problem?

Comment: @Stultuske I want to remove items from retailerConversionDtoList which doesn't exist in retailerDtoList how can I do that in optimized way?

Comment: Extract ids into a separate list and then use `contains()` function to remove items which IDs are not found `List<String> ids = retailerDtoList.stream().map(e -> e.getCode()).collect(Collectors.toList()); retailerConversionDtoList.removeIf(e -> !ids.contains(e.getRetailerCode()));`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'd use a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>`, that (usually) makes the `contains` check faster.

Answer (score 0):

In 8 or newer Java versions, you can simply use stream API to do it:

```java
Set<String> retailerCodes = retailerDtoList.stream().map(t -> t.code).collect(Collectors.toSet());
retailerConversionDtoList = retailerConversionDtoList.stream()
    .filter(t -> retailerCodes.contains(t.retailerCode))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Before Java 8, then you need to do some hard work by looping:

```java
Set<String> retailerCodes = new HashSet<>();
for(RetailerDto retailer: retailerDtoList){
    retailerCodes.add(retailer.code);
}

List<RetailerExcelConversionDto> newRetailerConversionDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < retailerConversionDtoList.size(); i++){
    if(retailerCodes.contains(retailerConversionDtoList.get(i).retailerCode))
         newRetailerConversionDtoList.add(retailerConversionDtoList.get(i));
}
```

or

```java
Set<String> retailerCodes = new HashSet<>();
for(RetailerDto retailer: retailerDtoList){
    retailerCodes.add(retailer.code);
}

for(Iterator<RetailerExcelConversionDto> it = retailerConversionDtoList.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    RetailerExcelConversionDto next = it.next();
    if(!retailerCodes.contains(next.retailerCode))
         it.remove();
}
```